# Execute HTTP call once and cache value until some condition changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I am looking to cache the result of a specific Angular2 HTTP call (getting my user profile from the server), and I want that cache to remain valid until I update the profile.

This is the code I have, which does cache the value, but never updates it, even if the profile is changed.

```ts
readonly user$: Observable<User> = this.http
    .get(`${this.baseUrl}/me`)
    .map(r => r.json())
    .publishLast()
    .refCount();

updateProfile(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/me`, user);
    // cause the existing user$-subscriptions to update with the user value
}
```

Preferably I want the profile to update the existing subscriptions with the `user` value passed to `updateProfile`. Can this be done nicely in an Rx-y way, or do I have to resort to using a `Subject` and updating that manually?

Answer (score 0):

I was apparently just a few minutes away from the answer. A working solution seems to be to create a `Subject` for user updates.

Merge that subject with the HTTP observable (that you force to only execute once). Then, on update, you put the new `user` value into the subject. That gets you an initial HTTP request followed by cached responses.

```ts
private readonly userSubject = new Subject<User>();
readonly user$: Observable<User> = this.userSubject
    .merge(this.http
        .get(`${this.baseUrl}/me`)
        .map(r => r.json())
        .publishLast()
        .refCount()
    );

updateProfile(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/me`, user)
        .map(r => r.json())
        .do(() => this.userSubject.next(user));
}
```

Any more elegant approaches would be highly appreciated. :)